# Parsing strings into integers

Tags: parsing, rust

So I'm trying to find a pattern in a string and convert it to an integer.

Firstly I look for a string:

```
let haystack = "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n";
let needle = "HTTP/1.";

let http_location = haystack.rfind(needle);
if (http_location.is_some()) {
```

Now that I've found it I can think of two ways to get the numerical status. Either:

```
    let mut temp_str = haystack.char_at(http_location.unwrap());
    let status = String::from_str(temp_str);
}
```

Or:

```
    let status = String::from_str(&haystack[http_location.unwrap()]);
}
```

Unfortunately both of them are deprecated (and probably wrong anyway). What is currently the correct way of doing this?

Also, is this part stylistically correct?:

```
let http_location = haystack.rfind(needle);
if (http_location.is_some())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing is a wide and varied topic. There are easy parsing tools and there are performant parsing tools and a spectrum in between.

```
fn main() {
    let haystack = "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n";
    let needle = "HTTP/1.";

    let z: Option<u8> = haystack.rfind(needle).and_then(|pt| {
        let after_match = &haystack[(pt + needle.len())..];
        after_match.splitn(2, " ").next()
    }).and_then(|val| {
        val.parse().ok()
    });

    println!("{:?}", z)
}
```

Here, we use `rfind` as you did before, which can fail. We use `and_then` to run the closure if the result was `Some`. The first closure slices the string *after* the needle, then splits it on spaces, with a maximum of 2 parts. That can fail, so we use a second `and_then` to use `parse`, which can *also* fail with a `Result`, so we convert that into an `Option` to preserve the type.

And the end of this, we still might have failed, as the thing we parsed might not have been a parseable number!

Rust really helps you make explicit places you can fail, and you have to deal with them. ^_^

In this case:

1. Maybe the string doesn't have "HTTP/1." in it
2. Iterators have to end at some point, so they can return `None`.
3. Parsing a string to a number can fail.

Here's an alternate solution that uses the [regex crate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/index.html):

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let haystack = "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n";

    let re = Regex::new(r"HTTP/1.(\d) (\d+)\r\n").unwrap();
    let captures = re.captures(haystack).unwrap();
    let version: Option<u8> = captures.at(1).and_then(|version| version.parse().ok());
    let status: Option<u8> = captures.at(2).and_then(|version| version.parse().ok());

    assert_eq!(Some(1), version);
    assert_eq!(Some(200), status);

    println!("Version: {:?}, Status: {:?}", version, status);
}
```

You'll see that we have the same types of failure modes, but the structure is a bit different.

Or maybe a version that uses `Result` and `try!`:

```
#[derive(Debug,Copy,Clone,PartialEq)]
enum Error {
    StartNotFound,
    NotANumber,
}

fn parse_it(haystack: &str) -> Result<u8, Error> {
    let needle = "HTTP/1.";
    let pt = try!(haystack.rfind(needle).ok_or(Error::StartNotFound));
    let after_match = &haystack[(pt + needle.len())..];
    let val = after_match.splitn(2, " ").next().unwrap();
    val.parse().map_err(|_| Error::NotANumber)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse_it("HTTP/1.1 200\r\n"));
    println!("{:?}", parse_it("HTTP/1"));
    println!("{:?}", parse_it("HTTP/1.cow"));
}
```

Comment: Is this the way rust is supposed to be written in 'production'? It looks incredibly terse, seems like something which would be hard to understand by an author after being away from the code for some time. Anyway, could you explain what exactly is the function and syntax of '.and_then()'? I feel like official docs for it assume having some knowledge of functional programming which I don't have.

Comment: @andreyg beauty is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose! You can certainly rewrite it with more `match` statements or upgrade from an `Option` to a `Result` and then make use of the `try!` macro. I've added this and a regex example. I can't speak for the entire Rust community, but you should certainly write code that you can understand! *Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?* - [Brian Kernighan](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan)